# Python what approach is the best - "list of Task objects" or "class Tasks with variable list of elements"

Tags: python, list, class, process, multiprocessing

I want to implement a list of tasks, but I don't know which approach of the two is the best:

First:

```
class Tasks(object):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tasks = []

    def add(self, process, instance) -> None:
        self.tasks.append((process, instance, Result()))

# example usage:
tasks = Tasks()
tasks.add('process-1', 'instance-1')
```

or maybe:

```
class Task(object):

    def __init__(self, process, instance) -> None:
        self.process = process
        self.instance = instance
        self.result = Result()

# example usage:
tasks = []
task = Task('process-1', 'instance-1')
tasks.append(task)
```

The goal is to keep somewhere processes and their results when doing parallel tasks (multiprocessing library). Maybe some way is more pythonic? or just more OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly opinionated, and probably more suited for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

The first one is supposedly easier to use and a more "OOP" fashion, but I dislike it for various reasons: It restricts your containers to that specific task list, it's harder to extend, and you lose a lot of built-in list operations when using that structure (if you don't inherit from `collections.abc.MutableSequence`).

The second one is more akin to anemic object model. Some consider this to be an anti-pattern but I find numerous advantages in this approach here:

1. You have the builtin list capabilities.
2. Your task object is simple and can be extended / subclassed.
3. You can easily switch the container (set, list, tuple...).
4. Easier to handle multi-threading and multi-processing when the container object does not need to guard against such concurrent operations.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what would you say of merged solution of these two approaches? Like outer class named TaskList that creates and manages the objects of type Task.

Comment: @Alraku That you're overcomplicating things :-)
Best lesson I've learned throughout the years is KISS.